# How to change css background color dynamically in php using color from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

I have a grid of items with all their data stored in a database, but I want each of their hover overlays to be the color associated with that item in the database.

Using a color picker (jscolor) during the upload process, the hex code is stored in the database. I can then get the hex code but cannot figure out a way of dynamically styling the background-color of the overlay in php.

This is sort of what I'm trying to achieve:

[Color Overlay](http://jsfiddle.net/so7vzg4e/)

CSS

```
.overlay-custom {
position: absolute;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-moz-transition-property: opacity;
-ms-transition-property: opacity;
-o-transition-property: opacity;
transition-property: opacity;
  background-color:#00ff00;
  z-index:2;
```

I want to dynamically replace the background-color of this div class with the hex code from the database.

Comment: `filter` is not support in IE at all!

Comment: Just set a javascript variable in PHP with the hex value and then set the color with JavaScript.

Comment: is it not? damn.. could you suggest an alternative? That sound as though it would work. Could you possibly give me an example please? I'm a noob at javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an inline style using php when you originally output the .overlay-custom.

```
<?php
    // load overlay color from database somehow
    $overlay_color = get_overlay_color();
?>

<div class="overlay-custom" style="background-color:#<?php echo $overlay_color ?>"></div>
```

or

```
<?php
echo '<div class="overlay-custom" style="background-color:#' . $overlay_color . '"></div>';
?>
```

Then opacity and all that can still be adjusted in the css file.

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to put it in an echo? it also needs to add the #. Something like? echo '<div class="overlay-custom" style="background-color:#('$overlay_color')">';

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to get the # sign in there. See how I have edited the last line in the answer.

Comment: This is what I tried: echo '<div class="overlay-custom" style="background-color:#<?php echo $overlay_color ?>">'; echo '</div>';   however it didn't work

Comment: See my edit with the full echo. You didn't have correct php syntax in the above.

Comment: Ah! That was my problem. Damn syntax. Thanks so much, spent ages on that.